# Can you specify which variable to use at the start of the method in java?

Tags: java

I would love to shorten this code a little and possibly make it more easily readable for my teacher. The problem is that I don't know if i can do something like this. Here is code with an example:

```java
if((polelode1[x][y] || polelode1[x][y + 1] || polelode1[x][y + 2] || polelode1[x - 1][y + 1] || polelode1[x - 1][y + 2] || polelode1[x][y + 3])!= true){ //kontrola kolize
    polelode1[x][y] = true;
    polelode1[x][y + 1] = true;
    polelode1[x][y + 2] = true;
    polelode1[x - 1][y + 1] = true;
    polelode1[x - 1][y + 2] = true;
    polelode1[x][y + 3] = true;
    pocetparniku = pocetparniku + 1;
}
else {
    System.out.println("can't create boat on another boat!");
    drawAim();
}

if((polelode2[x][y] || polelode2[x][y + 1] || polelode2[x][y + 2] || polelode2[x - 1][y + 1] || polelode2[x - 1][y + 2] || polelode2[x][y + 3])!= true){ //kontrola kolize
    polelode2[x][y] = true;
    polelode2[x][y + 1] = true;
    polelode2[x][y + 2] = true;
    polelode2[x - 1][y + 1] = true;
    polelode2[x - 1][y + 2] = true;
    polelode2[x][y + 3] = true;
}
```

The problem is the `polelode1` or `polelode2` boolean field which I would love it to work something like this:

```java
if((p[x][y] || p[x][y + 1] || p[x][y + 2] || p[x - 1][y + 1] || p[x - 1][y + 2] || p[x][y + 3])!= true){ 
    p[x][y] = true;
    p[x][y + 1] = true;
    p[x][y + 2] = true;
    p[x - 1][y + 1] = true;
    p[x - 1][y + 2] = true;
    p[x][y + 3] = true;
}
```

Instead of `p` use `polelode1` or `polelode2`.
Is that possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what i've found out that you can make an empty boolean field and you can copy the values of another field. This is my best solution so far:

```
if (player == true) {
        p = polelode1; 
     }
  else {
        p = polelode2;
    }
    if((p[x][y] || p[x][y + 1] || p[x][y + 2] || p[x - 1][y + 1] || p[x - 1][y + 2] || p[x][y + 3])!= true){ 
        p[x][y] = true;
        p[x][y + 1] = true;
        p[x][y + 2] = true;
        p[x - 1][y + 1] = true;
        p[x - 1][y + 2] = true;
        p[x][y + 3] = true;
    }
```

some testing was done, found out the hard way. Anyhow thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a couple things. Like loop over the two polelode1, polelode2.

```
for(bool[][] p: Arrays.asList(polelode1, polelode2)){
    if((p[x][y] || p[x][y + 1] || p[x][y + 2] || p[x - 1][y + 1] || p[x - 1][y + 2] || p[x][y + 3])!= true){ 
        p[x][y] = true;
        p[x][y + 1] = true;
        p[x][y + 2] = true;
        p[x - 1][y + 1] = true;
        p[x - 1][y + 2] = true;
        p[x][y + 3] = true;
    }
}
```

You could make a method.

```
static void process(bool[][] p){
    // repeat code with p.
}
```

Then you could just call the method.

```
process(polelode1);
process(polelode2);
```

You could use a stream.

Comment: this is an interesting one for sure, im definitely going to try this! thanks matt

Answer (score 0):

You can create other method and call it; for example :

```
public boolean fct1(boolean[][] p){
    return !(p[x][y] || p[x][y + 1] || p[x][y + 2] || p[x - 1][y + 1] || p[x - 1][y + 2] || p[x][y + 3]);
}
public void fct2(boolean[][] p){
        p[x][y] = true;
        p[x][y + 1] = true;
        p[x][y + 2] = true;
        p[x - 1][y + 1] = true;
        p[x - 1][y + 2] = true;
        p[x][y + 3] = true;
}
```

and then

```
if(fct1(polelode1)){ //kontrola kolize
        fct2(polelode1);
        pocetparniku = pocetparniku + 1;
        }
        else {
           System.out.println("can't create boat on another boat!");
           drawAim();
        }

        if(fct1(polelode2)){ //kontrola kolize
        fct2(polelode2);
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is mostly what i have been looking for! just a little bit of tweaking and it will be done! Thanks!